# using ST-4 in antlr v4

Tags: antlr4, stringtemplate-4

Until now I use antlr 3.4 to create language-specific grammar, and make a translator for the language with ST-3, but after appearing antlr v4 and ST-4, I can not use the code that I wrote earlier. Are there examples of the use of ST-4 in antlr v4. Thank you,